# PHP Video conversion in background and call a php file

Tags: php, background, command, exec

I tried many options, but stuck here.
I have a video uploading feature on my site
All uploaded videos go in a process of conversion and I am making the command to run in background.

The command works fine so far.

however the main concern is to find out what was the command result, pass or fail?
If pass, then I need the command to call another php page immediately.

For example, you upload a video on facebook, it says the its uploading, once finished, it says your video is currently under conversion process and we will inform you once it is ready.

Same thing I want to do. How do I know that the video conversion process is completed and the video is now ready.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use popen http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php 
you also read output of command